# Cannot resolve viewModel injection with delegate style declaration

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel, android-custom-view

I have a custom view class. I need to use my viewModel class here but it doesn't allow it.

```
class CustomOverlayView(private val context: Context) {
  
    private val viewModel = SampleViewModel(context as Application)

}
```

Comment: please don't add code as images, others can't copy it. i'm guessing by viewmodels is only allowed inside fragments/activities

Answer (score 0):

I think i made it:

```
private val viewModel = SampleViewModel(context as Application)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).